# Blocked recursive attempt to activate part

Tags: eclipse, compiler-errors, jasper-reports

I am using JasperReports 5.2.0 in Eclipse Kepler 20130606-0932.  I am using Java 1.7.  I cannot find many other pages reporting this outside of using JSF or something code like.  I am just using the GUI and am wondering why this is happening.  This error happens whenever I go from a jrxml tab to any other tab.  It does not occur when I go from a different tab to a jrxml tab. I don't want to post the entire dump unless someone really wants to see it. Here are the first few lines of the stack trace though

```
Blocked recursive attempt to activate part

java.lang.IllegalStateException
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer$2.setFocus(ContributedPartRenderer.java:119)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabItem.setFocus(CTabItem.java:329)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setFocus(CTabFolder.java:2509)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.fixFocus(Control.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setVisible(Control.java:3819)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setSelection(CTabFolder.java:3049)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setSelection(CTabFolder.java:3006)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.showTab(StackRenderer.java:1101)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer$1.handleEvent(LazyStackRenderer.java:66)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:41)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:180)
```

Is there something I can try to resolve this error.  I already re-installed Eclipse and created a new Jasper project.  Still the same error every single time I tab.

Comment: Did you see this: [Blocked recursive attempt to activate part](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=415326)?

Comment: Looks like the code doing this check has been removed in 4.3.1